# How to fix black gloss paint bleed on brilliant white eggshell walls + paint stripped from walls

Tags: painting, paint, patching-drywall, spackling-paste

We are newbies to house renovation/decoration and have been having fun doing it ourselves in our first new home, however, there have been a few mishaps along the way as we learn how to do things.

We have 2 issues:

1. Black gloss bleed on brilliant white eggshell walls.
2. FrogTape stripping off paint from around Dado rail.

We painted our walls with brilliant white eggshell, then we painted our dado rails gloss black but unfortunately the black gloss paint has bled through the FrogTape. What would be the best way to fix this up? Do we need to remove the black gloss that had bled with white spirit or some alternative method? We're happy to take our time to do it but unsure of the best way to go about it as I would imagine just painting over the bleed with the white eggshell wouldn't work?

The second problem is how to patch up the stripped off paint from around the Dado rail. I've read in a few places that sanding down, spackling, priming and repainting is a good option, but is spackling more for larger dents in the wall rather than stripped paint?

Thanks in advance for any help!!!
Hope everyone had a festive holiday as much as they could during this time.

EDIT: Attaching close up photos:

[image: Paint peeling]

[image: Dado bleed]

Comment: Unless you're tearing chunks out of the wall, you're correct, not much need for spackling.

Comment: Are we talking latex paint?  It is soluble in water for the first week or so, just wet it for 5 minutes then scrape.  Latex is incredibly flimsy stuff...

Answer (score 1):

First rule of masking the wall when painting trim - you need to paint the trim like there is no masking at all.  With practice you can learn how to paint a good enough line that you don't need to mask at all but until then the masking is for protection for an "oops" it is not carte-blanch to just slap the paint on the trim plus all over the tape.

I suggest you use a razor to razor the black paint off the wall.  Then mask the black dado and use a artists' paintbrush to cover the areas that you scraped off the white paint.

spackle is for drywall so yes you can use it to fill dents in drywall.

Comment: The problem is OP did not run their fingernail down the business edge of the tape, and so it wasn't fully adhered and left gaps.  Even if you hand-lay a perfect line, if it touches the tape *at all*, it will wick under the tape given the conditions I just described.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when paint peels off in sheets it's due to poor bonding. The paint doesn't adhere for a few reasons: surface needs cleaning and sanding, the existing paint is not compatible with the new paint or climate is extreme making it to hot or cold.

Too repair the peeling area scrape off as much of the paint that will easily come off. Next you need to sand the area with 100-120 grit sandpaper. Don't sand so much of the drywall or wall surface to roughen it too much. Stay on the peeled paint edge and feather the edge. Damp sponge the wall to remove dust.

Since the wall is textured you'l have to apply a [texture coating](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LNSDN2) to the bare spots. After texture is dry paint as usual.

When using painters tape to define a line always firmly press the edge onto the surface. While the paint is still wet slowly pull the tape up and away from the wet paint edge at a 45 degree angle. If the paint dries along the tape edge it will pull away with the tape.

Comment: It's certainly an issue of novice painters being under-educated on prep and primer. Like Morpheus says to Neo in *The Matrix*, everybody falls the first time.  Prep = thorough washing with a TSP substitute, and scuff-sanding with a green 3M Scotchbrite pad to remove any old gloss and provide a nice micro-jagged surface for the paint to adhere to, we call that "tooth".  Just as paint won't adhere to glass, it won't adhere to glossy surfaces either.